# Customize elmah.axd output fields

Tags: asp.net, logging, elmah

ELMAH shows host, code, type, error, user, date and time by default on its error log web page. Is there any way to configure it and show other fields like IP or REFERER?

[image: elmah output example]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/homeshot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ELMAH is open-source.  You can download the source and make any modifications you like (within the terms of the license, of course.)

You should be able to trap any data made available by the `HttpConext.Request` object.  You'd have to modify the code that grabs and stores the data, and the database to make columns for that new data.

Comment: i will modify the source if i have to. i was hoping there was a built-in way to configure the displayed fields

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make those changes through configuration, you'd have to modify the source.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own error page.  Bind a datagrid to `ErrorLog.GetErrors()` and use whatever columns you want:

```
List<ErrorLogEntry> entries = new List<ErrorLogEntry>();
ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).GetErrors(0, 50, entries);
string ip = entries[0].Error.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
string referrer = entries[0].Error.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Comment: This almost works, except in the current version of Elmah (not sure if this used to be different), GetErrors() does not fully populate the ErrorLogEntry objects.  In particular, ServerVariables is empty.  You have to use GetErrors() and then for each ErrorLogEntry object, call GetError(id) to get a fully populated ErrorLogEntry object...