# ELMAH - Does it log the referring URL

Tags: c#, elmah

I've just set up ELMAH on one of my MVC sites and can't seem to find the referring URL in any of the error logs.

Is the referring URL reported?

[I've added the detail on the exception below to show that HTTP_REFERER is not included:

```
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  no-cache
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH 0
HTTP_HOST   secure.abc.co.uk
HTTP_USER_AGENT Test Certificate Info
HTTPS   on
HTTPS_KEYSIZE   128
HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE 2048
HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER C=US, O="Thawte, Inc.", OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT    O=secure.abc.co.uk, OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html, OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate, OU=Domain Validated, CN=secure.abc.co.uk
INSTANCE_ID 2
INSTANCE_META_PATH  /LM/W3SVC/2
LOCAL_ADDR  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
LOGON_USER  
PATH_INFO   /https:/secure.abc.co.uk/
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547211/customize-elmah-axd-output-fields

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the question you refer to relates to showing the referrer in the summary table. I'm talking about the actual details page.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the referrer is actually being sent in the request.

ELMAH won't display the HTTP_REFERER row if no referrer is actually passed.

This could be because of a browser setting, anti-virus, or the way you're making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Be sure to click on the 'Details' link for the error you're looking at. It's the `HTTP_REFERER` attribute.