# How to customize Error title in Elmah?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I want that at the "Error title" in Elmah there is no the full error stack Trace, as shown in the figure:
[image]

In the error title and error Detail on the same information. takes too much space.

**Is there any way to edit this setting?**
Names of this zones I take by html code of Elmah.axd

I use ASP NET MVC . And generate error in controller by this code:

```
ErrorSignal
            .FromCurrentContext()
            .Raise(new JavaScriptException(ErrorMessage));
```

Comment: Have a read of http://doingthedishes.com/2011/09/10/custom-errors-mvc-3-elmah.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2547232/955831